Efficiently Synchronizing Put/Call Ratios for Identical Contracts in a Tokio-based, Rust Quantitative Backtesting System
I am enhancing an event-driven quantitative backtesting system in Rust, which utilizes Tokio for asynchronous operations. The system's design involves multiple traders managed within a single MetaPortfolio, each responsible for a double-selling options strategy on identical commodity futures contracts but in opposite directions (puts and calls).
The critical requirement is to maintain a 1:1 put/call ratio at all times for the same commodity and contract type. The state management for MetaPortfolio is handled using Rust's Arc<Mutex<>> or Arc<RwLock<>>, but I am facing challenges in achieving precise synchronization, particularly due to slight timestamp discrepancies among trader event processes.
Specific Questions:

Optimal Synchronization: Given the necessity of maintaining exact 1:1 put/call ratios for the same contract, how can I leverage Rust's concurrency tools (Mutex or RwLock) in a Tokio environment to synchronize these ratios effectively?

Handling Timestamp Discrepancies: What are the best practices or patterns in Tokio to manage slight timestamp discrepancies that affect the accuracy of synchronization in real-time trading scenarios?

Testing Strategy Adjustments: Considering the system uses historical data for testing, what methodologies should I employ to simulate and validate the synchronization of put/call ratios effectively, ensuring the system behaves as expected under live trading conditions?


Insights or experiences shared on managing such synchronization challenges in high-frequency trading systems using Rust and Tokio would be greatly appreciated.
